# Problem managing voltage for sensors and LCD

Tags: power-supply, transistors, voltage-regulator

I have this 5V voltage regulator circuit that is supposed to power these 2 circuits:

1. NodeMCU (will automatically turn on if plugged in)
2. Turn on/turn off the LCD and sensor when the pushbutton (BTN1) is pressed. (The circuit on the right blue box.)

The problem is, when I read Q3's collector using a multimeter, it shows 5V,  but when the LCD and sensors are plugged in, the voltage drops. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: A power transistor like TIP32 typically hasn't got much gain. With 100K in the base there is too little base current to make it conduct significantly.

Comment: Wow thanks! Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

TIP32 has very low hFe, 10-50 according to datasheet, so it needs high base current.

You need to lower the value of R10 accordingly, but honestly the best solution would be to replace TIP32 with a P channel MOSFET which will have a lower voltage drop when turned on and will not require drive current. Make sure to pick a MOSFET that has a RdsON value suitable for your application according to desired maximum voltage drop at the current you'll use, and the datasheet should specify this RdsON at a Vgs of 4.5V. If it is only specified for a Vgs of 10V then it will probably not turn on with your 5V gate drive.

Note you could alos remove the 555 and do the switching with the micro.